# A Problem about finite group 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e.$ Suppose that for any two
elements $a,b\in G-\{e\}$ there exists an automorphism $f$ defined by $f(a)=b.$

a) Prove that all elements of $G-\{e\}$ have the same order.

b) If $G$ is finite, prove that it is abelian.

I attempt to solve part (a) as follows:
Let $\vert a \vert=m$ and $\vert b \vert=\vert f(a)\vert=n,$ for $m,n\in Z^+$

Then $a^m=e$ and $b^n=f(a)^n=e.$

But, $b^m=f(a)^m=f(a^m)=f(e)=e.$ So that $n/m.$

Also, $f(a^n)=f(a)^n=e=f(e),$ so that $a^n=e.$ Thus, $m/n.$ Hence $m=n.$

But, I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

I don't know how to solve part (b). I need a help on how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's only a very specific kind of finite group where every non-identity element has the same order.

Comment: So the solution of part (a) is wrong?

Comment: It was a hint for (b). Not a comment on your solution for (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for (a) is correct. For (b) a hint: under your condition $Z(G)$, the center of $G$ is the full group and it is thus abelian, unless $Z(G)$ is trivial.
By (a), the transitivity implies that all elements of $G$ except $1$ have the same order. Show that then this order has to be prime and $G$ is a non-trivial $p$-group. But then, it is folklore that the center of a non-trivial $p$-group is non-trivial.
So $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group in which all elements (except $1$) have order $p$. That is, it is an elementary abelian $p$-group and isomorphic to a finite direct product of copies of $C_p$. (If there are $n$ copies, $Aut(G)=GL(n,p)$ and this group works indeed transitively on the vector space $C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$.)

Comment: Is it correct to show part (b) as follows: Since $G$ is finite. Assume it is order is a prime, p. i.e. $\vert G \vert=p^n.$ Thus, $G$ is a p-group, and hence has non-trivial center, $Z(G)\neq \{e\}.$ Now, if $a\in Z(G),$ we have $f(a)=b\in Z(G),$ since $y\neq e.$ Therefore, $Z(G)=G$ and hence abelian?

Comment: Yes you almost got it, you still have to show that $|G|=p$-power. This can be done by applying Cauchy and the fact that all non-trivial elements have the *same* order. Got it?

Comment: Is this  correct to show it as follows? Assume that each non-trivial element in $G$ has order a power of $p.$ Let $q\neq p$ be a prime number dividing the order of $G.$ Then by Cauchy's theorem there exists an element of order $q,$ a contradiction. Hence, $G$ is of order a power of $p.$

Comment: One thing: suppose each element has the same order. Let the prime $p$ be a divisor of $|G|$, then by Cauchy there must be an element of order $p$. But all elements have the same order, so all elements have order $p$. Then you go to your argument. Well done!